# Get a div's Width & Height after adding childs to it

Tags: html, height, width, appendchild

After creating a Div 'MyParent' , and many childs with different widths&heights are added to this 'MyParent' . By the end, i want to know the final width & height of 'MyParent' in pixels. I've used the familiar functions to get a width & height , i got 0 in all attempts.

Here's a simple code :

```
var myPrt = document.createElement('div');
var C1 = document.createElement('div');
var C2 = document.createElement('div');
var C3 = document.createElement('div');

myPrt.appendChild(C1);
myPrt.appendChild(C2);
myPrt.appendChild(C3);

$(C1).css({position:absolute;left:-100px;top:100px;width:100px;height:50px;background:red});
$(C2).css({position:absolute;left:100px;top:-100px;width:75px;height:50px;background:yellow});
$(C3).css({position:absolute;left:150px;top:200px;width:90px;height:50px;background:black});

$(myPrt).height(); // returns 0
$(myPrt).css('height') // returns 0
$(myPrt).innerHeight(); // returns 0
$(myPrt).outerHeight(); // returns 0
myPrt.clientHeight; // returns 0
```

In simple way to get that ?

Because actually I've found a solution to this problem , but it acts in the Childs, create a loop that goes throw all the Parents Childs , then get the max left and min left of these childs , then it returns the distance between the min & max , and the same tip for the Height by getting the max/min top, however ,this tip needs childs to have an absolute position to get there left/top am looking for an existing jquery or javascript function that does that without absolute position for childs .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this JSFiddle, you're just being clumsy I think. You never added the myPrt div to the document for one.

The other issue is that you're not passing the css as a properly formatted javascript dictionary with string variables.

http://jsfiddle.net/FcSEG/1/

```
var myPrt = document.createElement('div');
$('body').append(myPrt);

var C1 = document.createElement('div');
var C2 = document.createElement('div');
var C3 = document.createElement('div');

myPrt.appendChild(C1);
myPrt.appendChild(C2);
myPrt.appendChild(C3);

$(C1).css('width','500');
$(C1).css('height','500')
$(C1).css('background','red');

alert($(myPrt).height());
```

Comment: Negative, testing myPrt.outerWidth , myPrt.innerWidth are returning nothin , $(myPrt).innerWidth(), $(myPrt).outerWidth() are returning 0 .

Comment: Post the actual css you're using then

Comment: I've updated the question and add some simple css . and i've tried myPrt.width; and nothing is coming out .

Comment: Maybe because i am using it inside a jquery plugin ? '_' , but the issue is that graphically evrything is correct :s

Comment: are you properly formatting the jquery plugin? You need to be careful, especially if you use the dollar sign inside of your plugin. Read up on it here: http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Comment: Here's the Issue, when you add position:absolute to the child, the width or height don't come out anymore , they're 0 , any sollution ?